Scala type erasure warning for non-generics scenario
I'm writing a custom serializer for Scala case classes and have a utility function to determine whether various symbols are case classes:
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

def isCaseClass(symbol: ru.Symbol): Boolean = (symbol.isInstanceOf[ru.MethodSymbol] &&
                                                  symbol.asInstanceOf[ru.MethodSymbol].isCaseAccessor) ||
                                                  (symbol.isInstanceOf[ru.ClassSymbol] &&
                                                  symbol.asInstanceOf[ru.ClassSymbol].isCaseClass)

The isInstanceOf checks lead to warnings but I don't know why:
abstract type reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
abstract type reflect.runtime.universe.ClassSymbol is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

I understand type erasure when generics are involved, e.g. JVM can't distinuguish List[Integer] from List[String] and we enter the realm of type tags to sort these sorts of issues. But in my case MethodSymbol is a subclass of Symbol so why the type erasure?
Could someone kindly explain?
Thanks,
David

Because you are doing instance type casting. All instance casting happens at runtime. So... you are doing unsafe casting which compiler can not type check.

That's not it, there is quote a lot of isInstanceOf that do not generate these. Here issue is that it's path-dependent type. After type erasure JVM only knows that is is some abstract universe.MethodSymbol instance (because that exist in the butecode) but cannot tell if the instance came from one value or another (on Scala 2 both compile time and runtime reflection share the same API and the "only" difference is where instance comes from, making all these types path-dependent).

@MateuszKubuszok Thanks for the explanation! Do you think this matches my answer, or did I make any mistake?

AFAIK when you pattern match on path-dependent types you very often end up with something that you know will work, but compiler doesn't (because it is missing the context that this particular value can only come from this particular place etc), so neither asInstanceOf/isInstanceOf/pattern matching helps. You use whatever you prefer, unit-test it against fall-through cases then slap @unchecked and document why it's necessary. It's not always the case - sometimes compiler does not show the warning, but in another similar case it does. In my own macros I often go with -Wconf in the end.

Sure, I was more wondering about whether the why matched. On the how of course it's more of a matter of context and I was only offering the possible workaround. :)

It matches because on JVM level it's some inner class. Java allows object's to have inner classes, they have a distinct Class etc, BUT the ownership is only checked in runtime, storing the owner in a dedicated field. Scala's path dependent types try to prove where each such inner class comes from and create a separate type for members of each value. Pattern-matching/type checking happens in the runtime, so it bypasses this proving mechanism, so as far as Scala can tell it is e.g. someones MethodSymbol but is it ru.MethodSymbol (ru is an instance)? It cannot tell, so it gives a warn.

As raised in a comment, I was originally going to raise that this is caused by the usage of type-casting, but changing the code to use pattern matching instead did not help:
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{MethodSymbol, ClassSymbol, Symbol}

def isCaseClass(symbol: Symbol): Boolean =
  symbol match {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => true
    case c: ClassSymbol if c.isCaseClass     => true
    case _                                   => false
  }

The warning is still there, but I would still in general recommend to use pattern matching instead of isInstanceOf/asInstanceOf (I remember Scala creator Martin Odersky mentioning in his "Principles of Functional Programming in Scala" on Coursera that he made the pair verbose on purpose to incentivize people to use pattern matching).
I'm not 100% sure about the specific reason why the warning appears in this context, but one possible explanation is that the actual thing backed by the Symbol itself might appear in a generic context, meaning that it is a parameter to a generic class. As such, the compiler cannot guarantee that the concrete implementation of Symbol is captured at runtime, leading to the warning.
As a workaround, if you are OK with this information not being captured if they appear as a generic argument, you can mark the types as @unchecked as follows:
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{MethodSymbol, ClassSymbol, Symbol}

def isCaseClass(symbol: Symbol): Boolean =
  symbol match {
    case m: MethodSymbol @unchecked if m.isCaseAccessor => true
    case c: ClassSymbol @unchecked if c.isCaseClass     => true
    case _                                              => false
  }

You can play around with this code here on Scastie.

I much prefer the match syntax and will switch to that (with the @unchecked directive).
